# Go check if string in slices of string

Tags: go

As a preface I'm coming from python, where I would have a list with my values instead of string slices and do "if x in list".  Please tell me if I'm doing this wrong.

I need to take input from the user, if it's contained in my sliced string then break out of my loop and continue, otherwise prompt the user again.  Right now I have this

```
package main

import (
    "bufio"
    "fmt"
    "os"
    "os/exec"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    reader := bufio.NewReader(os.Stdin)
    foundfdb := false
    fdbslices := []string{"f", "d", "b", "files", "directories", "both"}

    for {
        fmt.Print("Files, Directories, or Both: ")
        fdb, _ := reader.ReadString('\n')
        fdb = strings.ToLower(fdb)
        for i := range fdbslices {
            if strings.ContainsAny(fdbslices[i], fdb) {
                foundfdb = true
            }
        }
        if foundfdb = true {
            break
        }
    }
}
```

It seems ContainsAny() is giving me some false positives. There's got to be an easier way to do this, or is there?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`ContainsAny`](http://golang.org/pkg/strings/#ContainsAny) allows you to look for a specific character is in a specific string, and I do not think that's what you want. For one of my projects, I implemented a function to look for a string in a slice:

```
func InArray(a []string, e string) bool {
    for _, x := range a {
        if x == e {
            return true
        }
    }
    return false
}
```

Comment: Very useful function!  I also did strings.Trim(var, "\n") around my variable since the \n from my stdin was throwing things off.